# is this c code still not of a defined output?

Tags: c

I was reading C Traps and Pitfalls and read that the following code may work on some implementations and won't on others due to an undefined order of = and ++. Is this still true of C?

```
int i = 0;
while (i < n)
    y[i] = x[i++];
```

If so, that's really incredible.

Comment: Where have you been? Superman came and fixed all C compilers in the world. So finally it's safe to write terrible code.

Comment: If i count all the time I spent debugging such crappy code, I could have taken a whole year of vacation.

Comment: @Alexandre C.: Helpfully, gcc at least now warns on such code ("`y.c:5: warning: operation on 'i' may be undefined`")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing incredible. Pretty defined undefined behavior. Read more about [sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points). 
Just writing as:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < n)
{
    y[i] = x[i];
    i++;
}
```

is safer and more readable.

Answer (score 3):

The postfix `++` has a *result* and a *side effect*.  The result is the current value of the operand.  The *side effect* is that the operand gets incremented by one.  Where the problem comes in is that the side effect doesn't have to be applied immediately after the expression has been evaluated; it only has to be applied before the next sequence point.

From the C language standard ([n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)):

> **6.5 Expressions**
> ...
> 2 Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
> modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.<sup>72)</sup> Furthermore, the prior value
>  shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.<sup>73)</sup>
> ...
> 72) A floating-point status flag is not an object and can be set more than once within an expression.
>
> 73) This paragraph renders undefined statement expressions such as
>
> ```
>     i = ++i + 1;
>     a[i++] = i;
> ```
>
> while allowing
>
> ```
>     i = i + 1;
>     a[i] = i;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It is not particularly suprising that this code has undefined behaviour, because it's semantically ambiguous: In `y[i]`, which value of `i` is intended? The value before the increment, or after? (Bear in mind that the `=` operator does not specify that one side is evaluated before the other)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's still UB.

> § 1.9p7 At certain specified
>   points in the execution sequence
>   called sequence points, all side
>   effects of previous evaluations shall
>   be complete and no side effects of
>   subsequent evaluations shall have
>   taken place. (§1.9/7)

Answer (score 0):

Well, i++ means "increment i after using its value", so it I think it's correct (well, I changed idea reading the other posts). Rather I would do:

```
while((i++) < n)
    y[i] = x[i];
```